# How to fetch data from URL in ios

Tags: ios

Hey i'm new in ios please help in fetching data from this URL...

```
NSString *urlString = @" http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Indore&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=10&APPID=fc632e2569dbdbb07ca79e239faa0281";
```

Comment: see this https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Can u fetch this..for example

Comment: May be this is what you are looking for : https://github.com/skdevil/WeatherApp

you should have knowledge of installing POD for this project.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSUrlSession` like this:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Indore&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=10&APPID=fc632e2569dbdbb07ca79e239faa0281";
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // handle the response
}] resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Init the NSURLSession with a configuration
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

//Create an URLRequest
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yourURL"];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Create POST Params and add it to HTTPBody
NSString *params = @"api_key=APIKEY&email=example@example.com&password=password";
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//Create task
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    //Handle your response here
}];

[dataTask resume];
```

Comment: `sendSynchronousRequest` was deprecated in iOS 9. In fact, you shouldn't be using `NSURLConnection` at all as it has been replaced by `NSURLSession`.